# Quanto mais queries no MySQL maior o consumo?

Tags: mysql, query

Estou desenvolvendo um site e meu código está usando muitas queries/consultas no MySQL de uma vez só, estou tentando diminuir essas queries para o menor número já que acho que quanto mais consultas mais recursos serão consumidos, estou certo?

Exemplo 1:

```
$busca = $conexao->query("SELECT nome FROM graficos");
$busca2 = $conexao->query("SELECT nascimento FROM graficos");
```

Exemplo 2:

```
$pegadeumavez = $conexao->query("SELECT nome, nascimento FROM graficos");
```

O Exemplo 1 teria o mesmo consumo de Exemplo 2? Digo qualquer tipo de consumo como memória RAM, CPU, bytes, processamento, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

boa noite 
a ideia ai é bem simples...quanto mais condesada for a sua consulta (ou seja, quanto mais dados você conseguir pegar de uma única vez) melhor, o maior gargalo que as aplicações tem hoje é o chamado Server Round Trip, ou seja a quantidade idas ao servidor para pegar dados , quanto menos vezes melhor. claro que cabe ao bom senso também não fazer uma mega consutla que retorna um zilhão de linhas, se possível quebre em pequenas cargas. Mas respondo, sim quanto mais dados em uma úncia consulta melhro para a perfomance da sua aplicação.